# Which scenario is more probable?

Tags: probability

Jean and Lisa are playing chess. Probability that Jean wins a game is two times less probable, than probability that Lisa wins a game.
Which of two scenarious is more probable:

1. Out of 5 games Jean wins 2
2. Out of 9 games Lisa wins 3

(Ties doesn't count)

So far I supposed that I have to use Bernoulli's formula:
$$P(X=m)=C_n^mp^mq^{n-m}$$, where $C_n^m=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$, $p$- probability that each person wins and $q=1-p$.

That led me to:

1. $P(X=2)=\frac{5!}{2!(5-2)!}\cdot p_1^{2}\cdot q_1^3=10\cdot p_1^2 \cdot q_1^3$ (for Jean)
2. $P(X=3)=\frac{9!}{3!(9-3)!}\cdot p_2^{3}\cdot q_2^6=84\cdot p_2^3
       \cdot q_2^6$ (for Lisa)

I also know that $p_1=0.5\cdot p_2$, therefore by placing this inside $1.$:

1. $P(X=2)=\frac{5!}{2!(5-2)!}\cdot (0.5\cdot p_2)^{2}\cdot (1-0.5\cdot p_2)^3=\frac{5 p_2^2}{2}-\frac{15 p_2^3}{4}+\frac{15 p_2^4}{8}-\frac{5 p_2^5}{16}$

And when $q_2=1-p_2$ is placed inside 2.:

2. $P(X=3)=\frac{9!}{3!(9-3)!}\cdot p_2^{3}\cdot (1-p_2)^6=84 \left(p_2^3-6 p_2^4+15 p_2^5-20 p_2^6+15 p_2^7-6 p_2^8+p_2^9\right)$

So know I understand, that I have done something to resolve my problem, but how would I compare those two expressions to find out which probability is the largest?

Comment: Why not calculate $p$ and $q$ first from the fact that one is twice the other?

Comment: ties don't count = ties don't occur, or we have some unknown probability of a tie?

Comment: Your exponents on $q_1$ and $q_2$ are wrong: they should be $5-2=3$ and $9-3=6$, respectively. And the exponent on $p_2$ should be $3$, not $2$.

Comment: It is considered, that there is only two possible outcomes- winning or losing a game.

Comment: So am I missing the fact, that probabilities of Jean and Lisa winning should add up to 1 and therefore be $p_1=0.25, p_2=0.5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let J and L be the events that Jean and Lisa win respectively; by assumption $$P(J)=2P(L)$$ and by virtue of the fact that one of Jean or Lisa always wins, then $$P(J)+P(L)=2P(L)+P(L)=1$$ so it follows that P(J)=$2/3$ and P(L)=$1/3$. Using the formula you've mentioned for a Bernoulli random variable we calculate the probability that in 5 games Jean wins 2 as $$\binom{5}{2}(2/3)^2(1/3)^3\approx.1646$$ and the probability that in 9 games Lisa wins 3 as $$\binom{9}{3}(1/3)^3(2/3)^6\approx.2731.$$ So the 2nd scenario is more probable than the first.